# javascript -Dynamic pagination pure Js

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to create dynamic pagination in pure Javascript. 
I'm running in a couple roadblocks, like trying to create dynamic pagination and link the page numbers to show the right items. Here is the code I'm struggling with and please see the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Delano83/pen/XjYxkQ) to see the entire project.

Initial variables:

```
var currentPage = 1;
var numPages = 0;
var studentsPerPage = 10;
var index;
```

Creating the pagination in Js:

```
var paginationFilter = function pageFilter (nbOfEntries) {
var pagination = document.createElement('div');
var ulList = document.createElement('ul');
var liList = document.createElement('li');
var pageLink = document.createElement('a');

pagination.setAttribute("class", "pagination");
pageLink.setAttribute("class", "navlink");
pageLink.setAttribute("href", "#");

pagination.appendChild(ulList);
ulList.appendChild(liList);
liList.appendChild(pageLink);

return pagination;  };
```

Here are my functions to find the length of my student list, find the number of pages to create, hide all the elements and show only the 10 first items on my list. The other items should be on the next pages.

```
var numberOfStudents = function () {
var numberOfStudents = eachStudent.length;
return (numberOfStudents);}

//Finding the number of pages
var numberOfPages = function () {
    var numberOfPages = parseInt(numberOfStudents() / studentsPerPage);
    if ( numberOfStudents() % studentsPerPage > 0 ){
        numPages += 1;
    }
    return numberOfPages;
}
//Hiding all the students
var hideAll = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStudents(); i++) {
        eachStudent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
};

//Display only the 10 first items on the page
function showStudents (number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < studentsPerPage; i++) {
        index = number * studentsPerPage - studentsPerPage + i;
        eachStudent[index].style.display = "block";
        console.log(index);
    } 
};



function createPages () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfPages(); i++) {
        page.appendChild(paginationFilter());
        var navlink = document.getElementsByClassName(".navlink");
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(i);
        //i'm trying to append the node to the link in order to create the pagination links dynamically but it's not working...
        navlink.appendChild('linkText');
        console.log(linkText);
    }
};
```

So I'm wondering how to create the pagination dynamically depending on the number of items on the list. These items are filtered dynamically as well, so the number of pages need to update 'live'.

link to fiddle: http://codepen.io/Delano83/pen/XjYxkQ

Any remarks or comments on my code are appreciated!

Comment: Why recreate the wheel? Try bootstrap or a jQuery plugin like this... http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: I need to use pure Js only :) Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 2):

Try this codepen example of a pure javascript implementation.

https://codepen.io/karpovsystems/pen/fFHxK

**NOTE: This is not my code, just found it on codepen**

```
var Pagination = {

    code: '',

    // --------------------
    // Utility
    // --------------------

    // converting initialize data
    Extend: function(data) {
        data = data || {};
        Pagination.size = data.size || 300;
        Pagination.page = data.page || 1;
        Pagination.step = data.step || 3;
    },

    // add pages by number (from [s] to [f])
    Add: function(s, f) {
        for (var i = s; i < f; i++) {
            Pagination.code += '<a>' + i + '</a>';
        }
    },

    // add last page with separator
    Last: function() {
        Pagination.code += '<i>...</i><a>' + Pagination.size + '</a>';
    },

    // add first page with separator
    First: function() {
        Pagination.code += '<a>1</a><i>...</i>';
    },



    // --------------------
    // Handlers
    // --------------------

    // change page
    Click: function() {
        Pagination.page = +this.innerHTML;
        Pagination.Start();
    },

    // previous page
    Prev: function() {
        Pagination.page--;
        if (Pagination.page < 1) {
            Pagination.page = 1;
        }
        Pagination.Start();
    },

    // next page
    Next: function() {
        Pagination.page++;
        if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size) {
            Pagination.page = Pagination.size;
        }
        Pagination.Start();
    },



    // --------------------
    // Script
    // --------------------

    // binding pages
    Bind: function() {
        var a = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
            a[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Click, false);
        }
    },

    // write pagination
    Finish: function() {
        Pagination.e.innerHTML = Pagination.code;
        Pagination.code = '';
        Pagination.Bind();
    },

    // find pagination type
    Start: function() {
        if (Pagination.size < Pagination.step * 2 + 6) {
            Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.size + 1);
        }
        else if (Pagination.page < Pagination.step * 2 + 1) {
            Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.step * 2 + 4);
            Pagination.Last();
        }
        else if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2) {
            Pagination.First();
            Pagination.Add(Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2 - 2, Pagination.size + 1);
        }
        else {
            Pagination.First();
            Pagination.Add(Pagination.page - Pagination.step, Pagination.page + Pagination.step + 1);
            Pagination.Last();
        }
        Pagination.Finish();
    },



    // --------------------
    // Initialization
    // --------------------

    // binding buttons
    Buttons: function(e) {
        var nav = e.getElementsByTagName('a');
        nav[0].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Prev, false);
        nav[1].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Next, false);
    },

    // create skeleton
    Create: function(e) {

        var html = [
            '<a>&#9668;</a>', // previous button
            '<span></span>',  // pagination container
            '<a>&#9658;</a>'  // next button
        ];

        e.innerHTML = html.join('');
        Pagination.e = e.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        Pagination.Buttons(e);
    },

    // init
    Init: function(e, data) {
        Pagination.Extend(data);
        Pagination.Create(e);
        Pagination.Start();
    }
};



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Initialization
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

var init = function() {
    Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('pagination'), {
        size: 30, // pages size
        page: 1,  // selected page
        step: 3   // pages before and after current
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: Could you brielfy explain how this code would help me to filter the page by 10 items? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code is not complicated. JS code is less than 100↓ lines.

```html
<!-- CSS is not essential. You can ignore it. -->
<style> 
  :root { /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--* */
    --color-radial-inside: #ff2200;
    --color-radial-outside: #343232;
  }

  html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(contain, var(--color-radial-inside, #F2F2F2), var(--color-radial-outside, #635e5e));
  }

  body {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  body:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: .1rem .2rem .3rem .2rem;
    border-top: .1rem solid #AEAEAE;
    border-bottom: .1rem solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #DADADA;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DBDBDB, #E2E2E2);
  }

  #pagination a, #pagination i {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1.375rem;
    color: #7D7D7D;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.625rem;
    padding: .3rem 0 .2rem 0;
    user-select: none;
  }

  #pagination a {
    margin: 0 .2rem 0 .2rem;
    border-radius: .4rem;
    border: .1rem solid #E3E3E3;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 .1rem 0 0 #FFF, 0 .1rem .2rem #666;
    text-shadow: 0 .1rem .1rem #FFF;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3F3F3, #D7D7D7);
  }

  #pagination i {
    margin: 0 .3rem 0 .3rem;
  }

  #pagination a.current {
    border: .1rem solid #E9E9E9;
    box-shadow: 0 .1rem .1rem #999;
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D0D0D0, #EBEBEB);
  }
</style>

<body>
<div id="pagination"> <!-- id is for CSS only -->
  <!-- here is a sample that we want to create as below
  <a>◄</a>
  <span>
    <a>1</a><i>...</i><a>2</a><a class="current">3</a><a>4</a><i>...</i><a>5</a>
  </span>
  <a>►</a>
  -->
</div>
</body>

<script type="module">
  export class Pagination {
    /**
     * @param {Array} data
     * @param {Number} step Before and after current
     * @param {Number} selectedPage Selected page
     */
    constructor(data, step = 1, selectedPage = 1) {
      this.data = data || []
      this.size = this.data.length // Pages size
      this.page = selectedPage
      this.step = step
    }

    Build(targetElem) {
      const htmlFrag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
<a>&#9668;</a>
<span></span>
<a>&#9658;</a>
`)// &#9668; ◄ previous button  |  &#9658; ► next button

      const frag = htmlFrag.querySelector(`span`)

      // Calculate the startPage and endPage.
      let startPage = this.page - this.step
      let endPage = this.page + this.step

      if (startPage <= 0) {
        endPage += -startPage + 1
        startPage = 1
      }

      if (endPage >= this.size) {
        startPage = Math.max(startPage - (endPage - this.size), 1)
        endPage = this.size
      }

      // first
      if (startPage > 1) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
          `<a ${this.page === 1 ? 'class="current"' : ''}>1</a><i>...</i>`)
        )
      }

      // middle
      for (let page = startPage; page <= endPage; ++page) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
          `<a ${this.page === page ? 'class="current"' : ''}>${page}</a>`
        ))
      }

      // last
      if (endPage < this.size) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(
          `<i>...</i><a ${this.page === this.size ? 'class="current"' : ''}>${this.size}</a>`
        ))
      }

      // middle "a" click
      htmlFrag.querySelectorAll(`span a`).forEach(aElem => {
        aElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.page = +aElem.innerText
          this.Build(targetElem)
        })
      })

      // Prev and next click
      const [aPrev, ...others] = htmlFrag.querySelectorAll(`a`)
      aPrev.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        this.page--
        if (this.page < 1) {
          this.page = 1
        }
        this.Build(targetElem)
      })

      // next
      others.at(-1).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        ++this.page
        if (this.page > this.size) {
          this.page = this.size
        }
        this.Build(targetElem)
      })

      targetElem.innerHTML = "" // clear
      targetElem.append(htmlFrag)
    }
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    const testData = [...new Array(100).keys()]
    const startPage = 2
    const step = 3
    const pagination = new Pagination(testData, step, startPage)
    pagination.Build(document.querySelector(`div`))
  }

</script>
```